# Unable to get results when querying the Azure DNS zone list

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

I am following [this tutorial to create a cloud based app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/cloud-native-apps-orchestrate-containers/3-exercise-create-aks-instance).

I am very unfamiliar with Azure as its my first time doing something like this. On unit 7, it instructs me to run this command in bash:

```
az aks show --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --name $CLUSTERNAME -o tsv --query addonProfiles.httpApplicationRouting.config.HTTPApplicationRoutingZoneName
```

However, nothing is returned when I run this command in ACL. I suspect it has something to do with the ingress file, the sample output its supposed to have is below. I am to replace the example url with the output of the previous command but am unable to. What do I need to do?

```
#ingress.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cna-express
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: addon-http-application-routing
spec:
  rules:
  - host: cna-express.<exampleURL.eastus.aksapp.io>
    http:
      paths:
      - path: / # Which path is this rule referring to
        pathType: Prefix
        backend: # How the ingress will handle the requests
          service:
            name: cna-express # Which service the request will be forwarded to
            port: 
              name: http # Which port in that service
```

I tried running a shortened version of the command:

```
az aks show --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --name $CLUSTERNAME -o tsv
```

Which gave me this output:

> None            1       None                    None
> cna-demo-aks-dns-ow17um7l.portal.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io   1.26.6
> False   None    cna-demo-aks-dns        None    True    None
> cna-demo-aks-dns-ow17um7l.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io     None    None
> /subscriptions/c8137442-32ff-421c-b2df-a50fe30b402b/resourcegroups/learn-cna-rg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/cna-demo-aks
> 1.26.6  None    eastus  100     cna-demo-aksMC_learn-cna-rg_cna-demo-aks_eastus              None
> None    None    Succeeded       None    learn-cna-rgKubernetesOfficial
> None    Microsoft.ContainerService/ManagedClusters      None    None

I tried to use `cna-demo-aks-dns-ow17um7l.portal.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io` from this result as the host url in the ingress file, ran the next command to deploy the ingress manifest to my cluster, recieving this:

```
aalpert [ ~/mslearn-cloud-native-apps-express/aks ]$ kubectl apply -f ./ingress.yaml
ingress.networking.k8s.io/cna-express created
```

However, when I try to check if the deployment was successful, the address is blank, as seen in the image.
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the addon (HTTPAplicationRouting) to the cluster.

Use:

```
az aks enable-addons --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --name $CLUSTERNAME --addons http_application_routing
```

Then run this command again:

```
az aks show --resource-group $RESOURCEGROUP --name $CLUSTERNAME -o tsv --query addonProfiles.httpApplicationRouting.config.HTTPApplicationRoutingZoneName
```

Note that this will add the RETIRED version of the addon, as per this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing.

To install the new (preview) version, follow the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/app-routing